# How do I cast an __NSMallocBlock__ to its underlying type in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, casting, swift3, unsafe-pointers

I had [a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39512988/17294) to help test `UIAlertController` that worked in Swift 2.x:

```
extension UIAlertController {

    typealias AlertHandler = @convention(block) (UIAlertAction) -> Void

    func tapButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {
        let block = actions[index].valueForKey("handler")
        let handler = unsafeBitCast(block, AlertHandler.self)

        handler(actions[index])
    }

}
```

This fails under Swift 3.x with `fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes`, which tempts me to believe there might be a way to make the cast work. Can anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 26):

Found a solution that works in Swift 3.0.1

```
extension UIAlertController {

    typealias AlertHandler = @convention(block) (UIAlertAction) -> Void

    func tapButton(atIndex index: Int) {
        if let block = actions[index].value(forKey: "handler") {
            let blockPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged<AnyObject>.passUnretained(block as AnyObject).toOpaque())
            let handler = unsafeBitCast(blockPtr, to: AlertHandler.self)
            handler(actions[index])
        }
    }

}
```

(Originally, the `block` value was the actual block, not a pointer to the block—which you obviously can't cast to a pointer to `AlertHandler`)

Answer (score 11):

My answer is based on @Robert Atkins's, but shorter.
The problem here is that, `valueForKey` returns a `Any` typed object, and because in Swift,

```
MemoryLayout<Any>.size == 32
MemoryLayout<AnyObjcBlockType>.size == 8
```

an assertion will be triggered in `unsafeBitCast` when casting between types of different sizes.

One work-around is to create an intermediate wrapper and transform back to raw pointer, which satisfies `MemoryLayout<UnsafeRawPointer>.size == 8`.

A much simpler way is to create an indirect reference directly using protocol `AnyObject`, relying on the fact that `MemoryLayout<AnyObject >.size == 8`, we can write following valid code:

```
typealias AlertHandler = @convention(block) (UIAlertAction) -> Void

func tapButton(atIndex index: Int) {
    if let block = actions[index].value(forKey: "handler") {
        let handler = unsafeBitCast(block as AnyObject, to: AlertHandler.self)
        handler(actions[index])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your UIAlertController is an action sheet you can modify Robert's answer to dismiss the UIAlertController before you executed the handler.

dismiss(animated: true, completion: {() in handler(self.actions[index])})

I was using this extension for testing and without this modification my assertions for presented view controller were failing.